# Unit tests for connectException and IOException

Tags: java, junit

I have unit test that tests to see if a method is throwing an error or not.

```
@Test
public void getStockPriceWithNetworkErrorThrowsException()
{
    StockPriceFetcher stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError = Mockito.mock(StockPriceFetcher.class);
    when(stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError.getPrice("YHOO"))
            .thenThrow(new ConnectException("Network error"));

    assetValue = new AssetValue(stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError);

    try
    {
        assetValue.getStockPrice("YHOO");
        fail("Expected exception for network error.");
    }
    catch(ConnectException e){
        assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "Network error");
    }
}
```

`getPrice` is a method from the interface `stockPriceFetcher`, and `getStockPrice` simply returns what `getPrice()` returns. I want a `ConnectException` to be thrown, but I have an error in the catch block because `ConnectException` is never thrown in the try block.

Is there anyway I can make this try block throw a `ConnectException`?

Comment: How does the `getStockPrice` wrapper method handle the exception thrown by `getPrice`? Does it throw the exception further?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but getStockPrice is called in a later method, and this method catches the ConnectException that getStockPrice receives from getPrice

Comment: Then that's your answer. I'll post below

Comment: You should not write unit tests that check the text of exceptions. `ConnectException` is provided by the JDK and it does not contain the text `"Network error"`, and, even if it did, it could change in any release, or with any change of locale. All you should be testing here is whether the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve that is replacing the following line:

> when(stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError.**getPrice**("YHOO"))

with the line:

> when(stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError.**getStockPrice**("YHOO"))

But make sure that the getStockPrice() include a try {} catch(ConnectException e){} block.

It seems that you do not throw the ConnectException in the getStockPrice() method.

```
getStockPrice(String str) {

    getPrice(str) {
     //  Here the ConnectException is thrown
     }
   // here should appear another catch that throws the error to the upper level
}
```

Without the try{} catch{} block in the getStockPrice() method, the exception can not be catch in any place the method is called. 
That is why you should also implement a Mock to the getStockPrice().

When you add the try{} catch(ConnectException e) {} block it will work great.

Answer (score 0):

Augment your `@Test` annotation with its [`expected`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#expected()) parameter.

```
@Test(expected=ConnectException.class)
public void testConnectExceptionThrown() {
    // your test here
}
```

The test will only pass if the expected exception is thrown from the test method's execution. If the test concludes without an uncaught ConnectException, it will be treated as a failure. That's generally how you test for exceptions.

Of course, if you want to test the message of the exception, then that's not going to cut it. You're going to need to mostly do it the way you've already written. However, I would move the assertion out of the catch block.

```
@Test
public void getStockPriceWithNetworkErrorThrowsException()
{
    StockPriceFetcher stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError = Mockito.mock(StockPriceFetcher.class);
    when(stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError.getPrice("YHOO"))
            .thenThrow(new ConnectException("Network error"));

    assetValue = new AssetValue(stockPriceFetcherWithNetworkError);

    String exceptionMsg = null;
    try
    {
        assetValue.getStockPrice("YHOO");
        fail("Expected exception for network error.");
    }
    catch(ConnectException e){
        exceptionMsg = e.getMessage();
    }

    assertEquals("Should have thrown ConnectException with correct message",
        "Network error", exceptionMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In light of what was discussed in comments, I am almost sure your problem is that `getStockPrice` does not throw the exception it gets from `getPrice` further so essentially it does not get to the point of it being thrown to the instance which calls `getStockPrice` (e.g. your test class).

What you can do is either:

- modify your test to expect exactly what happens in the `catch` block from `getStockPrice` **if** that's the behaviour you want your system to have **OR**
- modify your `getStockPrice` method to throw the exception it gets from `getPrice` instead of catching it i.e. add a `throws` declaration to it and remove the `try...catch` blocks. Then your test will behave as expected the way it is written right now